# "No overload matches this call" typescript error react-input-mask with react-hook-forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting this error in code below

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
import { Input } from "antd";

interface FormData {
  phoneNumber: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const { control, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormData>();
  const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        name="phoneNumber"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({ field }: any) => (
          <InputMask
            mask="(999) 999-9999"
            maskChar=""
            value={field.value}
            onChange={field.onChange}
            onBlur={field.onBlur}
          >
            {/* Errors here */}
            {(inputProps: any) => {
              return <Input {...inputProps} />;
            }}
          </InputMask>
        )}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hardcore-visvesvaraya-gldpw5?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30006356hmictws1u%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30002356hyse2xxxj%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30003356h51dlfh9b%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30005356hislbivoh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clt3xioo30002356hyse2xxxj%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30002356hyse2xxxj%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xu3nm0002356h7zweu7ke%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A4%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A23%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A4%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A23%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt3xu3nm0002356h7zweu7ke%2522%257D%252C%2522clt3xioo30005356hislbivoh%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30004356h4po6brvy%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30005356hislbivoh%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30004356h4po6brvy%2522%257D%252C%2522clt3xioo30003356h51dlfh9b%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clt3xioo30003356h51dlfh9b%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

I'm not understanding why I am getting this error. How does the overload not match if I put it as any? Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: `InputMask` needs a ReactNode but you provide a function

Answer (score 0):

May be you code just remove these lines:

```
{(inputProps: any) => {
              return <input {...inputProps} />;
            }}
```

And keep `<InputMask />` without children if you don't need that.

Comment: that's intended. I'm using antd and i want to preserve the Input styles which inputmask does not.

Comment: Then you should put your antd `Component` as a child instead of a function.

Comment: I've tried that and I get another error `react-input-mask.js?v=72f8b7bf:33 Uncaught (in promise) Invariant Violation: react-input-mask: children must be a function`